# Getting parts of a string value, the uncomplicated way

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

I've put together the following SQL that works and gives the expected result that I'm looking for, with the 2 test cases I have.

I'm wondering, however, is there a cleaner better way of doing it?

```
 DECLARE @Value varchar(500) = 'Charge : Landlord Rent  Amount changed from 1300.00 to 1301.00  Daily Amount changed from 42.74 to 42.77'
--    DECLARE @Value varchar(500) = 'Charge : Landlord Rent  Amount changed from 300.00 to 301.00  Daily Amount changed from 42.74 to 42.77'    


    SELECT 
        LEFT(name, charindex(' ', name) - 1) as FromAmount
    from 
    (
    SELECT
        SUBSTRING(@Value,
                  CHARINDEX('Amount changed from', @Value) + 20,
                  CHARINDEX('Daily Amount', @Value, CHARINDEX('Amount changed from', @Value)) -
                      CHARINDEX('Amount changed from', @Value) - 20) AS name
    ) t1
    
    SELECT 
        RIGHT(name, charindex('To ', name)) as ToAmount
    from 
    (
    SELECT
        SUBSTRING(@Value,
                  CHARINDEX('Amount changed from', @Value) + 20,
                  CHARINDEX('Daily Amount', @Value, CHARINDEX('Amount changed from', @Value)) -
                      CHARINDEX('Amount changed from', @Value) - 20) AS name
    ) t1
```

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: Yes, don't do it in T-SQL. SQL, the language, is a query language and pretty terrible at text manipulation, much less parsing. Parse the data *before* you insert it in the database. Worst case, use SQL Server 2016+'s R or Python support to create parsing scripts. Store the *clean* data in the database

Comment: SQL 2017
No option there Panagiotis, it's a vendor application that I'm extracting it from.

Comment: Another option is to store the unstructured data as XML or, since 2016, JSON. XML and JSON parsing and querying are available but still, not as fast as storing the data in proper fields, indexing them and querying them

Comment: `it's a vendor application that I'm extracting it from` parse it on the client, not T-SQL. You can create a simple C# console app that will read the data from the database, parse it and do whatever you want with it.

Comment: The client? I'm needing to extract it for use within a query to compare the from and to amounts.

Comment: You no longer have a query though. You have a complex stored procedure that will eventually produce something, after a long time. You can't use indexes or statistics any more, not even restrict what data is read. Everything has to be read and parsed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I need to join with multiple tables, etc so I need to do it within T-SQL so I get back the data I need from it. It's only a few thousand rows so its very fast.

Comment: If you're willing to jump through a few hoops, you could create a SQLCLR function in C# that would parse the string and extract the data. The code would be simpler and faster than T-SQL, the data available in queries BUT you wouldn't benefit from indexing. If you tried to filter or aggregate by amount, you'd still have to parse all rows to extract the values.

Comment: @Philip Do you need the `from 42.74 to 42.77` part from the input text?

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
DECLARE @Value varchar(500) = 'Charge : Landlord Rent  Amount changed from 1300.00 to 1301.00  Daily Amount changed from 42.74 to 42.77'

SET @Value= REPLACE(@VALUE,SUBSTRING(@VALUE,CHARINDEX('Daily Amount changed from',@Value),LEN(@VALUE)),'')
--DECLARE @Value varchar(500) = 'Charge : Landlord Rent  Amount changed from 300.00 to 301.00  Daily Amount changed from 42.74 to 42.77'    

DECLARE @expres  VARCHAR(50) = '%[:,~,@,#,$,%,&,*,(,),a-z,A-Z,!]%'

WHILE PATINDEX( @expres, @Value ) > 0
SET @Value = Replace(REPLACE( @Value, SUBSTRING( @Value, PATINDEX( @expres, @Value ), 1 ),''),'-',' ')


SELECT SUBSTRING(TRIM(@Value),1,CHARINDEX('  ',TRIM(@Value))) AS FROM_Amt ,SUBSTRING(TRIM(@Value),CHARINDEX('  ',TRIM(@Value)),LEN(TRIM(@Value))) AS To_Amt
```

Sample O/P:

[image]

Comment: @panagiotiskanavos - Plz Check Now

Answer (score 1):

You can try parsing your string as XML and then read the node values. Following an example:

```
DECLARE @Value varchar(500) = 'Charge : Landlord Rent  Amount changed from 1300.00 to 1301.00  Daily Amount changed from 42.74 to 42.77'

;WITH cteXML AS(
  SELECT CAST('<Charge>'
             + REPLACE(
                       REPLACE(
                               REPLACE(
                                       REPLACE(
                                               REPLACE(
                                                       REPLACE(@Value
                                                              ,'  '
                                                              ,' '
                                                              )
                                                      ,' Daily Amount changed from '
                                                      ,'</to></Rent><Daily><from>'
                                                      )
                                              ,'Amount changed from '
                                              ,'<from>'
                                              )
                                      ,' to '
                                      ,'</from><to>'
                                      )
                              ,'Charge : Landlord Rent '
                              ,'<Rent>'
                              )
                      ,'  Daily Amount '
                      ,'</to></Rent><Daily>'
                      )
             + '</to></Daily></Charge>' AS XML) AS ValueXml
),
cteXMLColumns AS(
  SELECT ValueXml.value('(Charge/Rent/from)[1]', 'DECIMAL(19,4)') AS RentFrom
        ,ValueXml.value('(Charge/Rent/to)[1]', 'DECIMAL(19,4)') AS RentTo
        ,ValueXml.value('(Charge/Daily/from)[1]', 'DECIMAL(19,4)') AS DailyFrom
        ,ValueXml.value('(Charge/Daily/to)[1]', 'DECIMAL(19,4)') AS DailyTo
    FROM cteXML
)
SELECT *
  FROM cteXMLColumns
```